# Is there a way to extract time spent on parsing, rendering, etc. during WebView load?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I know how to get the total loading time of a web page by using onPageStarted() and onPageFinished() in WebViewClient.

What I want to know is whether there is a way to extract detailed information on web page load such as time spent on parsing, rendering, etc.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `method profiling` in eclipse to get memory as well as time taken in each step of your application.

Have a look here.
http://www.jpct.net/wiki/index.php/Profiling_Android_Applications

have a lok on its output format `Time/Call` cell provides information regarding time ellapsed on particular action

Thanks
Deepak

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the info, and I have one more question. I want to show the traceview information by running the traceview app on the android device itself, not from the computer. Is there a way to do that? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [WebView#debugDump()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#debugDump%28%29)?  It is marked as "deprecated", but it might still prove useful.  Also try [Profiling with Traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html), using the `Debug.startMethodTracing()` and `Debug.stopMethodTracing()` methods around your WebView start/finish locations.  Then follow the instructions above to download the trace file and load it into `traceview`, to see where time is spent.

Comment: Thanks Joe, it helped me a lot. I have one more question, the same question that I wrote on the comments above. Could you help me out? Thanks again.